# How can I get nomal form when I convert an array into an equation?

Tags: code

I have an array `a & b & c & d & e & f & g` and I want to convert this array in the form `sqrt{a x + b} + sqrt{c x + d} = e` with answer `S=\{f,g\}`. egreg helped me with this code. Thank you very much.

```
\documentclass[,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\changearray}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \gdef\@changearraybody{}%
  \makerow#1\relax
  \begin{longtable}{@{}ll@{}}
  \@changearraybody
  \end{longtable}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
\def\makerow{\@ifnextchar\relax{}{\@makerow}}
\def\@makerow#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7\\{%
  \g@addto@macro\@changearraybody{%
  $\sqrt{\@checkone{#1}x+#2}-\sqrt{\@checkone{#3}x+#4}=#5$
  &
  \hfill  Answer. $S=\{#6,#7 \}$ 
  \\}
  \makerow
}
\def\@checkone#1{\edef\next{\zap@space#1 \@empty}\ifx\next\@fixedone\else#1\fi}
\def\@fixedone{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{All negative coeffients}
\changearray{-10 & -6 & -9 & -8 & 1 & -33 & -1 
  \\}
How can I obmit the sign $+$ in front of the  sign $-$? And then, we get
\[\sqrt{-10x-6}+\sqrt{-9x-8}=1.\]
\section{$a=-1$ or $c=-1$}
\changearray{-1 & -6 & -9 & 8 & 1 & -3 & -1 
  \\}
How can I obmit  the  number $1$ in front of the  sign $-$? and get $\sqrt{-x-6}+\sqrt{-9x+8}=1$
\section{$b=0$ or $d=0$}
 \changearray{ -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & -1 & 7
   \\}
   How to get
   \[\sqrt{-x}+\sqrt{x+2}=2\]
\end{document}
```

But some situations I cannot solve.

1. **First case.** All negative coefficients, e.g. 
   `-10 & -6 & -9 & -8 & 1 & -33 & -1`, I got

[image]

How can I get the equation in the form?

[image]

2. **Second case** `a = -1` or `c=-1`

I used `\changearray{-1 & -6 & -9 & 8 & 1 & -3 & -1   \\}`. I got

[image]

How can I get the equation in the form?

[image]

3. **Third case** `b = 0` or `d = 0`.

I used 
`\changearray{ -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & -1 & 7 \\}` and I got

[image]

How can I get the equation in the form?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\checkval` macro. My code prints directly the equation (without tables of numbers etc.), so you can modify this for your needs.

```
\def\changearray#1{\changearrayA #1\\\\\end}
\def\changearrayA#1\\{\ifx\end#1\end \changearrayC \else 
   \endgraf$\changearrayB#1&$\endgraf \expandafter\changearrayA \fi}
\def\changearrayB#1&#2&#3&#4&#5&#6&#7&{%
    \sqrt{\checkval{#1} =1:{}, =-1:{-}, =#1:{#1},; x
          \checkval{#2} =0:{}, <0:{#2}, =#2:{+#2},;}
   -\sqrt{\checkval{#3} =1:{}, =-1:{-}, =#3:{#3},; x
          \checkval{#4} =0:{}, <0:{#4}, =#4:{+#4},;}
   =#5 \quad \hbox{Answer. } S = \{#6,#7\}. 
}
\def\changearrayC#1\end{\fi}
\def\checkval#1{\def\tmp{#1}\let\next=\checkvalA \checkvalA}
\def\checkvalA #1:#2,{\ifnum \tmp#1 #2\def\next##1;{}\fi \next}

\changearray{-10 & -6 & -9 & -8 & 1 & -33 & -1 \\
              -1 & -6 & -9 & 8 & 1 & -3 & -1 \\
              -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & -1 & 7}
```

Comment: What if #1 = 0?

Comment: @wipet If I have a long array, how can I do?
\changearray{-10 & -6 & -9 & -8 & 1 & -33 & -1\\
 -1 & -6 & -9 & 8 & 1 & -3 & -1\\
 10 & 9 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 136 \\
 10 & 9 & 9 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 28 \\}

Comment: @minthao_2011 I supposed that you use your own solution for this (because I don't know the consequences in your document) and you add only my idea about `\checkval` macro. Nevertheless I upgraded my code in order to it can process more than one line of data.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If #1=0 (and #2=0 too, for example) and this is real need for this application then it would be interesting implementation with nesting parameters of `\checkval`. But if this is not real need for this very particular application then I will not waste time. Zero votes is not good motivation for this.

Comment: @wipet Can you align Answer?

Comment: @wipet And how to the equations are numbered?

Comment: @minthao_2011 I repeat: my code is only idea of using `\checkval` macro. You cannot expect that I give you full solution. You probably have full solution and you can only add the idea about `\checkval` to your solution. Why didn't you do it?